# Combining php stream sockets with eventSource

Tags: php, sockets, eventsource

I am trying to learn about sockets in PHP and lots of reading has brought me down the route of `stream_socket_server()`.

I got a basic chat working between two terminals in linux using code similar to what is below and was hoping my next step would be to build a chat or a notification system on the web.

**What I expected to happen:**

The event listener in eventSource.html would listen for an event in the while loop and output the message received from a linux terminal that was running server.php

**What is happening:**

Everything from the point of view of eventSource.html is working as it should. So if I was to take away the entire purpose of this and just replace the message with a standard string `Hello World` then this succesfully outputs `<li>message:{Hello World}</li>` every second.

However once I try and read data from the terminal nothing is appearing except `<li>message: {}</li>` every second. It is worth noting that when I run server.php it waits for the client, and when I then run eventSource.html it sucessfully connects.

I am misunderstanding how this works? I assumed that every second in the while loop it would look out for data in that stream.

Or am I going down a completely wrong road in terms of learning sockets.

server.php (I load this from the terminal in linux)

```
<?php 
$PORT = 20226;          //chat port
$ADDRESS = "localhost"; //adress
$ssock;     //server socket
$csock;     //chat socket
$uin;       //user input file descriptor

$ssock = stream_socket_server("tcp://$ADDRESS:$PORT");      //creating the server sock

echo "Waiting for client...\n";
$csock = stream_socket_accept($ssock);          //waiting for the client to connect
                                        //$csock will be used as the chat socket
echo "Connection established\n";

$uin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");       //opening a standart input file stream

$conOpen = true;    //we run the read loop until other side closes connection
while($conOpen) {   //the read loop

    $r = array($csock, $uin);       //file streams to select from
    $w = NULL;  //no streams to write to
    $e = NULL;  //no special stuff handling
    $t = NULL;  //no timeout for waiting

    if(0 < stream_select($r, $w, $e, $t)) { //if select didn't throw an error
        foreach($r as $i => $fd) {  //checking every socket in list to see who's ready
            if($fd == $uin) {       //the stdin is ready for reading
                $text = fgets($uin);
                fwrite($csock, $text);
            }
            else {                  //the socket is ready for reading
                $text = fgets($csock);
                if($text == "") {   //a 0 length string is read -> connection closed
                    echo "Connection closed by peer\n";
                    $conOpen = false;
                    fclose($csock);
                    break;
                }
                echo "[Client says] " .$text;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

client.php gets loaded from eventSource.html below

```
<?php 

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
header("Content-Type: text/event-stream\n\n");
$PORT = 20226;    //chat port
$ADDRESS = "localhost"; //adress

$sock = stream_socket_client("tcp://$ADDRESS:$PORT");
$uin = fopen("php://stdin", "r");

while (1) {
$text = fgets($uin);

  echo 'data: {'.$text.'}';
  echo "\n\n";


  ob_end_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);

}
```

eventSource.html

```
<script>
    var evtSource = new EventSource("client.php");

    evtSource.onmessage = function(e) {
    var newElement = document.createElement("li");

  newElement.innerHTML = "message: " + e.data;
  var div = document.getElementById('events');
  div.appendChild(newElement);
}
</script>
<div id="events">
</div>
```